# Isotope hide items results in error

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to hide images in isotope. However when I call

```
$grid.isotope('hide', $items)
```

I get an Uncaught TypeError: item.once is not a function.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: You need to post additional code. When are you hiding, When Filtering? Sorting? loading? A jsfiddle is the best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a misunderstanding

The function requires isotope objects and not elements.

https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope/issues/600

> reveal and hide are more internal methods, used with filtering, removing, and adding new item elements. But this issue and desandro/masonry#429 have me thinking that they might be more confusing then useful. Currently, they require Array of Isotope.Item, not elements or arrays, so you will need to use getItem to use it.